# Add Author's Role Badge on WordPress Posts List Table

Tags: php, wordpress

In WordPress edit posts list, if an author has a "verified" role I want to display a badge next to the author's display name. Any idea how to add the badge next to the "verified" author's display name?

I have tried to filter the get_the_author() function that was used on "class-wp-posts-list-table.php", but it didn't work.

```
    /**
     * Handles the post author column output.
     *
     * @since 4.3.0
     *
     * @param WP_Post $post The current WP_Post object.
     */
    public function column_author( $post ) {
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => $post->post_type,
            'author'    => get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ),
        );
        echo $this->get_edit_link( $args, get_the_author() );
    }
```

```
function verified_the_author( $author ) {
     global $post;
     $authorID = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
     $author_roles = $authorID->roles;
    if ( in_array('verified', $author_roles) ) {
    $author .= "<i class='fa fa-check-circle'></i>"; }
    return $author;
}

add_filter( 'get_the_author', 'verified_the_author', 10, 1);
```